# I wanted to try some python packages but I got this: "reportMissingModuleSource" and "reportMissingImports"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, package

I just started learning python and I wanted to use some packages. I'm using VS code. so, I copied this code from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) but it gave me this error:

```
"Import "matplotlib.pyplot" could not be resolved from source" and "Import "numpy" could not be resolved"
```

[image]

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 


x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))       
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the packages.

From the Python Environments window,

- select the default environment for new Python projects and choose the Packages tab.
- You will then see a list of packages that are currently installed in the environment.
- Install `matplotlib` by entering its name into the search field and then selecting the Run command: `pip install matplotlib` option. This will install matplotlib, as well as any packages it depends on.

Also in the link you provided, your issue is mentioned on the bottom with instruction on how to install packages.

Comment: Yeah it worked. Do you think that I should delete my question or keep it?

Comment: There's no reason to delete and in future it might help others.